# How can you make debounced search faster?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, search, input, debouncing

I've implemented a debounced search input to be able to search for notes in a list of notes. Although it works, it feels way too slow, even though the delay is set to 150ms. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have tried, but I am sure there's a better way to do it.

```
export const App = () => {
  
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState<string>("");

  const getFilteredNotes = (notes: string[], query: string) => {
    console.log("in getFilteredItems");
    if (!query) {
      return notes;
    }
    return notes.filter((note) => note.includes(query));
  };

  const filteredNotes = getFilteredNotes(notesList, query);

  const updateQuery = (str: string) => setQuery(str);

  const handleSearch = debounce(updateQuery, 100);


  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SidePanel showSidePanel={showSidePanel}>
        <Input value={query} onChange={handleSearch}/>
        <Button onClick={addNote}>Add note</Button>
        {filteredNotes.map((note: string, idx: number) =>
          <Note onChange={updateNote} remove={deleteNote} idx={idx} text={note} key={idx}/>
        )}
      </SidePanel>
      <ToggleButton onClick={toggleSidePanel}>Open</ToggleButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Faster than what? Where is the time actually being spent? What does “feels slow” actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

here a typescript example with 1s delay

1. set your timeout in a variable

```
let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

2. clear your timeout or run after delay

```
  onInput(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // each time you click you clear the 1s delay
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      // do you stuff like fetch(e.target.value)...
    }, 1000)
```